# Ubuntu rescue mode mount and backup files

Tags: mount, backup

I'm logged into the Ubuntu Recovery mode to backup my files.

The output of `sudo fdisk -l` is 
[image]

The output of `parted --list` is 
[image]

The output of `lsblk` and `mount | grep /dev/sd` is 
[image]

*Could you help me mount and take a backup?*

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and copy the output of `parted -l` (or `sudo parted -l`, if you're not root yet)? That provides more detailed output about what the partitions might contain.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still missing some detail I'd like to see. What do the commands `lsblk` and `mount | grep /dev/sd` tell us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all of your data is on the main partition you selected to be used as `/` (file system root) during the installation, that one should be already mounted when you select recovery mode in GRUB menu and then drop to a root shell. It's just mounted as read-only, so you have to

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

before you have write access to it.

To mount all partitions that would normally automatically get mounted at boot time, run

```
mount -a
```

Comment: didn't work, check this: http://prntscr.com/81w3hb

Comment: please check this as well!:http://prntscr.com/81wbln

Comment: Run `umount /dev/sda1` and `mkdir /mnt/hdd` and `mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/hdd`. Then you should be able to access the biggest partition (1.8TB) of your disk through the path `/mnt/hdd/*`.

Comment: please check what those commands return: http://prntscr.com/81xkfu

Comment: So as I see from screenshots you are not in root shell ( which should have # as prompt ). Are you logged in as a regular user ? If that's the case,  use sudo or sudo -i